# É recomendado usar chave primária natural?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, chave-primária

Chave primária natural é aquela que contém um dado real, e não apenas um valor aleatório, como um inteiro.

Exemplo:

```
// comum
CREATE TABLE pessoas (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  cpf INTEGER NOT NULL,
  // outros campos
);

// chave natural
CREATE TABLE pessoas (
  cpf INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  // outros campos
);
```

No caso acima eu utilizo o CPF da pessoa como chave, já que ele não se repete. Isso é recomendado?

Comment: Eu não usaria, e nem recomendo. No caso do CPF por exemplo, as vezes aparecem relatos de duas pessoas com o mesmo CPF. É raro, mas acontece. Ex http://g1.globo.com/fantastico/noticia/2014/02/mulheres-descobrem-que-alem-de-nomes-iguais-tem-o-mesmo-cpf.html

Comment: Entendo que foi um "Exemplo", como colocado, não é a duvida sobre CPF... Podemos imaginar um  sistema onde ninguém quer saber de registro que não tenha seu CPF. Já trabalhei com demanda similar, de revista, que para existir precisava ter um [ISSN](http://www.issn.org/understanding-the-issn/assignment-rules/the-issn-l-for-publications-on-multiple-media/)... CPF e ISSN são bons exemplos de [URNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_name) garantidas por uma   [authority control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authority_control#Standards). Neste contexto vejo uma pergunta interessante.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Versão curta** - Não, não é recomendado.

**Versão longa** - Eu entenderia a sua pergunta da seguinte maneira:

> O benefício de possuir um banco de dados sem artifícios de processos
>   *versus* o custo de manutenção de uma chave primária natural resulta
>   positivamente?

Vamos então à uma enumeração rápida de pontos positivos de cada opção:

### Chave Primária Natural

- Representação real do escopo de dados
- Não satura o escopo com um identificador artificial

Nesta implementação, seu modelo de dados é o mais próximo possível do universo representado pelo escopo. Cruzamento de dados de bases externas são facilitados pelo fato que seu dado é utilizado como identificador natural (por exemplo, CPF ou carteira de identidade.)

### IDs, GUIDs e derivados

- Desacopla o processo dos dados representados
- Provê ao acoplamento seus próprios mecanismos de vínculo e garantia de unicidade
- Previne bloqueio por repetição de dados
- Permite a presença de dados parciais
- Segurança por ofuscamento do dado natural
- Dados imutáveis previnem fragmentação de índices
- Diminuição dos erros de importação e mesclagem de dados

Um modelo de dados é desenhado de maneira a reproduzir o comportamento dos dados presentes no universo definido pelo escopo. Entretanto, sendo um modelo abstrato, ele deve prover seus próprios mecanismos para permitir esta representação.

Caso você utilize um modelo natural, *você está delegando a responsabilidade sobre unicidade*. Caso essa unicidade seja violada, o seu modelo será impactado negativamente. Por exemplo, duas pessoas com o mesmo CPF, ou um CPF que foi erroneamente digitado e que por acaso já está presente no banco de dados.

Em situações onde os dados são incompletos e os campos identificadores naturais ainda não estão presentes, um modelo destes ainda assim permitiria a criação de registros contendo uma representação parcial.

Comment: Gostei da resposta longa, acho que podemos imaginar um  sistema onde ninguém quer saber de registro que não tenha seu CPF. Já trabalhei com demanda similar, de revista, que para existir precisava ter um [ISSN](http://www.issn.org/understanding-the-issn/assignment-rules/the-issn-l-for-publications-on-multiple-media/)... CPF e ISSN são bons exemplos de [URNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_name) garantidas por uma   [authority control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authority_control#Standards). Voce considera URNs como bons candidatos ao seu conceito de Chave Primária Natural?

Comment: @PeterKrauss algumas experimentos mentais - 1) Registro parcial: onde o formato final do registro necessariamente irá possuir uma URN obrigatória, mas o processo de criação é fragmentado (por exemplo, criação de um usuário no sistema onde o primeiro passo é a confirmação de email). 2) Garantia de unicidade: Até mesmo ISSN não é único para publicações (vide JID). Se unicidade for importante para o sistema, então necessariamente um mecanismo suplementar deve ser implementado. 3) expansão de escopo: Como lidar com uma nova necessidade (por exemplo, ISBN em adição ao ISSN?)

Comment: Respondendo: nestes casos, URNs podem sim ser candidatos se e apenas se várias condições forem positivas; ainda assim, a solução final pode possuir uma rigidez difícil de justificar. Uma avaliação de custo/benefício sobre futuras atualizações do modelo pode ser necessária.

Answer (score 12):

Eu diria que não é recomendado.

#### 1. Nem todo mundo tem CPF

Como fazer com estrangeiros? E os menores de idade que ainda não possuem CPF? Nesse casos eles não podem criar conta?

#### 2. Geradores de CPF

Imagine que alguém foi criar uma conta em um site qualquer e por desconfiança ou até mesmo por má intenção tal pessoas resolveu não usar seu próprio número de CPF e pegou um número de CPF através de um gerador. Um belo dia o verdadeiro portador do número do CPF resolve criar um conta no site, obviamente ele vai ser impedido pois o sistema o informará que já existe uma conta atrelada àquele CPF. Como resolver tal situação?

Não estou dizendo que é impossível de resolver, mas você estará criando uma complexidade extra apenas por que não não quis usar um auto incremento como chave primária e resolveu usar o CPF.

#### 3. Mesmo usuário não pode ter múltiplas contas

Existe algum excelente motivo para não deixar o usuário ter duas contas? Você já não permitiu que a criança possuísse uma conta, e também não permitirá que o responsável tenha duas contas (uma para ele e outra para seu filho, por exemplo). Talvez ele pegue o CPF da vó, ou então use um gerador (sigh).

#### 4. E se o usuário não consegue recuperar senha?

Suponha que o usuário criou uma conta e nunca mais acessou, depois de um tempo ele tenta acessar novamente, mas ele não lembra a senha e também perdeu a senha ou trocou de e-mail. Você precisará de um plano extra para recuperar a senha do usuário e manter exatamente a mesma conta que ele criou a princípio.

De novo, não estou dizendo que é impossível, mas é uma complexidade extra que você terá que desenvolver, enquanto você poderia apenas deixar o usuário criar uma conta nova.

#### 5. Como lidar com troca de titularidade?

Supondo uma assinatura de uma Sky por exemplo, se um belo dia eu quiser transferir a titularidade sem ter que cancelar a conta atual, devolver o aparelho, assinar uma nova conta e receber um novo aparelho. Como fazer?

Ok, você pode mudar a PK e usar *triggers* ou seja lá o que for, mas é novamente outra complexidade extra no seu sistema.

#### 6. Qual a vantagem de usar o CPF como PK?

A não ser que você tenha um excelente motivo, a única "vantagem" que eu pensei até o momento foi: economizar um campo na tabela.

Comment: +1 Ótima resposta!

Comment: É bom lembrar que o CPF é uma chave artificial na base da Receita.

Answer (score 5):

Não é uma boa ideia. Veja alguns argumentos:

1 - Uma pessoa pode tanto ser uma pessoa física (CPF) quanto uma pessoa jurídica (CNPJ).

2 - Caso a pessoa não tiver o documento em mãos, ou o usuário que for cadastrar não tiver esse dado, o cadastro simplesmente não seria efetuado, ou você teria que inventar um CPF temporário e ainda por cima válido (caso o sistema faça validação de CPF).

3 - Futuramente o governo poderá extinguir o CPF e criar um documento único, ou quem sabe mudar o nome `CPF` para outro nome.

4 - Não acho uma boa ideia uma PK depender de um dado informado pelo usuário. Se quiser que exista apenas uma pessoa com um determinado CPF, basta criar uma UNIQUE KEY.

Answer (score 5):

Não é uma ideia boa e existe várias razões para isso!
Primeiro a regra do negócio pode mudar, seja por uma mudança em lei, ou porque o negócio mudou, e neste caso, você teria problemas com a chave primária natural.
É recomendado criar a tabela com uma chave genérica (ID) e se for necessário, garantir que a chave natural seja um Unique Key.
Criando uma Unique Key você garante que a chave natural nunca seja repetida, mas o relacionamento com outras tabelas, será realizado pela chave "genérica", o ID.