# Valores que podem ser inseridos como chave primária

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Eu tenho um código próprio da empresa do produto que é formado por duas letras e 4 números (exemplo: XX0000), é aconselhável usar esse código como chave primária ou criar um outra coluna com campo código e colocar `unique` para esse código?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Esse código é único e nunca será alterado para cada linha (entidade)? Se for assim é uma boa candidata para chave primária sim. Caso contrário eu sugeriria usar outra, alguma artificial ([*surrogate*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277091/101)), um `id` de controle interno do banco de dados provavelmente auto-incrementada de alguma forma.

Toda chave primária deve ser obrigatoriamente única (e que não aceite nulos, até porque só poderia aceitar um para ser única mesmo) e idealmente que nunca seja trocada (por isso que CPF é uma chave primária ruim, nada garante que a pessoa terá o mesmo CPF para sempre, imagina e-mail, telefone e coisas do tipo).

Tome cuidado porque muita gente acha que um código nunca será mudado, mas nem sempre isso é verdade, já vi muitas situações que códigos que nunca iam mudar e um dia mudaram. As empresas reestruturam a forma de manipular seus produtos por diversas razões. Esse `XX` é uma preocupação, porque isso tem cara de ser um classificador e classificações mudam, é raro mas mudam. O problema não é ter letras, o problema é a estabilidade do dado.

Até pode fazer diferente, mas idealmente chaves primárias devem ser sempre crescentes. Tem banco de dados que obriga ser, não é o caso do MySQL.

Dou uma [resposta que fala sobre mitos sobres dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/110655/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

A **chave primária** deve ser um campo, ou conjunto deles, que **identifiquem o registro**.

Se o campo citado por você se enquadra nessa situação, ele poderá ser uma chave primária.

Apenas uma ressalva: este campo no formato XX0000 será representado por um `varchar` no seu banco. Talvez o uso de um **campo numérico** para representar a chave primária (**uma coluna auto incremento, por exemplo**) traga melhor performance, mas teria que ser avaliado. Se assim optar, poderia fazer de seu campo uma `unique key` para evitar duplicação de valores.