# Retornar ultimo valor inserido na tabela onde o valor não é identity?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de retornar o ultimo  valor da  chave primária inserido na tabela, mas minha chave primária é `CPF` então não posso usar `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

Answer (score 7):

Não há um *T-Sql* para isso. Você só usa *[SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175098.aspx) ou [IDENT_CURRENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175098.aspx)* desde que a coluna seja Identity.

*Recomendo as seguintes leituras:*

- *[Best way to get identity of inserted row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)*
- *[É recomendado usar chave primária natural?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28507/%C3%89-recomendado-usar-chave-prim%C3%A1ria-natural)*

Uma alternativa é adicionar um campo `DataInsercao` com tipo `datetime` a estrutura de sua tabela. Por `default` esse campo deve receber a data atual, a função *[GETDATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188383.aspx)* pode ser útil neste caso.
Assim você poderá ordenar por data mais atual e verificar qual o ultima registro inserido.

O Select deve estar mais ou menos assim:

```
Select top 1 * from MinhaTabela Order By DataInsercao DESC
```